# How to create 'resources' folder in Intellij?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, resources

When I try to create a new package, I right click on it and then click on the 'mark directory as' option. However, I have nothing but the 'exclude' option. Is it because I should connect my project with Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it your project imported from outside? In this case you should set your project as a Maven project, take a look here--> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/importing-project-from-maven-model.html

Comment: Thanks, as I was thinking :)

Comment: Happy for this... please if it helps you, vote it :)

Comment: sorry, but i can't yet

Comment: What's up? was it not able to be converted?